# Iterate over a table to get the all possible successors

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table with each row giving me for a ID the predecessor and successor. A is replaced by B and B is replaced by C and C is replaced by D.

```
library(data.table)
data  <- data.table(
            ID           = c(001, 001, 001),
            Predecessor  = c("A", "B", "C"),
            Successor    = c("B", "C", "D"))
```

What I would like to achieve is to have all possible successors showing up in one row like the following format:

```
result  <- data.table(
             ID           = 001,
             Predecessor  = "A",
             Successor    = "B",
             Successor2   = "C",
             Successor3   = "D")
```

I have tried with a inner join, but this works only once. How can I iterate over the table until there is no successor anymore?

Comment: Iterate, likely with a `while` loop that looks for "no merge occurred" and then exiting. You may want to limit the number of attempts it makes in case there is the possibility of circular logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data defines a graph - so perhaps it makes sense to formalize this property and then extract all vertices?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

# define sample data
df  <- tibble(
  ID           = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  Predecessor  = c("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y"),
  Successor    = c("B", "C", "D", "Y", "Z")
)

# convert to graph objects
df1 <- df |> 
  nest(.by = ID) |> 
  mutate(graph = map(data, igraph::graph_from_data_frame))

# list vertices for each ID
df1 |> 
  reframe(list_rbind(map(graph, ~as_data_frame(.x, "vertices"))),
          .by = ID)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>      ID name 
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 A    
#> 2     1 B    
#> 3     1 C    
#> 4     1 D    
#> 5     2 X    
#> 6     2 Y    
#> 7     2 Z
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>